# How to resolve opernerp_background_worker and openerp_gevent could not be started in Odoo 9?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, bitnami

I am using Bitnami Odoo 9 stack and it is under root control in hosting server. I edited openerp-server.conf file through gedit, after that 'opernerp_background_worker and openerp_gevent could not be started' errors are occuring while re-starting Odoo stack services.

Anyone having any idea on how to deal with this, would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

Edited the configuration files through command line with sudo nano.No problems of permission conflicts occured from this.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned:

> I edited openerp-server.conf file through gedit

What did you change on that configuration file? There could be some miss-configuration.

I recommend you to take a look the the Odoo Log file and the Apache Log files in order to identify the issue. Take a look to the documentation below:

https://docs.bitnami.com/?page=apps&name=odoo&section=odoo-log

https://docs.bitnami.com/?page=apps&name=odoo&section=how-to-debug-apache-errors

Comment: Thanks Juan for your efforts and I was able to figure out the problem. Being under root profile, i went onto edit the configuration file through gedit(which is non-root mode), so problem occured when changes were not getting saved in gedit.